# How to change the value of input type in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-input

I have a simple html form i.e.

```
  <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" id="registration-form">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form-reg-fullname" data-form-field="Name" id="form-reg-fullname">
     <input type="hidden" name="return" value=""/>
  </form>
```

in `<script>` tag I am doing validation and changing the value of return:

```
 <script>
   $('#registration-form').submit(function () {
   var fname = $.trim($('#form-reg-fullname').val());

$("#return").val("http://localhost:9000/app/fname");

});
</script>
```

Validation is working successfully while submitting the form but I am getting empty value in `return` `input type`. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing an id on the return input, you just have a name. So it should look like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" id="return" value=""/>
```

That way when you call the input in js with `$('#return')` it will get it by it's proper id.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value=""/>

$("#return").val("http://localhost:9000/app/fname");//PROBLEM RESIDE Here
```

See what are you doing you are trying to assign the value to a selector that have id = return . But you don't have any element with this id however , you have an element with the same name.You can resolve this in two ways:

First selecting the element by its name:

```
$("input[name='return']").val("http://localhost:9000/app/fname");
```

or you can assign the id attribute to your input element as

```
<input type="hidden" id="return" name="return" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the value of input with `id="return"` which doesn't exist.

```
$("#return").val("http://localhost:9000/app/fname");
```

You should either give an id to input tag as

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" id="return" value=""/>
```

Or change script to

```
$("input[name='return']").val("http://localhost:9000/app/fname");
```

Answer (score 0):

You call node using id in jquery , your return input doesnt have the Id called return

```js
   $('#registration-form').submit(function () {
   var fname = $.trim($('#form-reg-fullname').val());

$("#return").val("http://localhost:9000/app/fname"); //setting the value
console.log($("#return").val()); //getting the value
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" id="registration-form">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form-reg-fullname" data-form-field="Name" id="form-reg-fullname">
     <input type="hidden" name="return" value="" id="return"/>
  </form>
```